# How to use - 'deno fmt' in denon

Tags: deno, deno-fmt

I am adding `"fmt": true` to the `denon.json` file so that auto formatting is run when saving the file. But this is not working. How do I get auto formatting to run when the file is saved?

Comment: i will suggest use pre-commit hook better performance. or autosave of vscode.

Comment: add your config for others reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/denosaurs/denon/blob/master/README.md) of Denon the `fmt` option is not present, so it does nothing.

You may add a separate script to `denon.json` for this and run it simultaneously with your other scripts. The allow flags needs to be nulled, use it as `denon format`:

```
"scripts": {
  "format": {
    "cmd": "deno fmt",
    "desc": "Format the code.",
    "allow": []
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it seems that you can't have the `watch` option for when running `deno fmt`, so I have the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://deno.land/x/denon@2.4.7/schema.json",
  "scripts": {
    "start": {
      "cmd": "deno run app.ts"
    },
    "format": {
      "cmd": "deno fmt",
      "watch": false
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, now I need to run `denon format` manually :(